# production rule from tree structure with re but not without nltk

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract rule from tree structure without using Natural Language Toolkit(NLTK) .
For ex; The tree structure is:

```
( NP-TMP ( NNP December  )  ( CD 1998  )  )  \n
```

and I want to extract rule such that:

```
NP-TMP -> NNP CD
NNP -> 'December'
CD -> '1998'
```

How can I do that with `re` library in Python without using "nltk"?

Comment: Are all the trees like that?

Comment: you need to describe multiple rules so it's clearer whether you just doing simple extraction from a fixed pattern or parsing of s-expressions.

Comment: Regular expression is *regular* for that matter it is a subset of recursive grammars. I.e. it is not able to parse a product of recursive grammar, which is what you are trying to do. However, if for some reason you are opposed to using NLTK, you may look into just any Lisp parser (they aren't usually very complex) to figure out how to parse this. There are other libraries, which help you build special kinds of parsers. I've not used [this one](http://code.google.com/p/funcparserlib/), but it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

A very non elegant solution would be

```
import re

s_expr = "( NP-TMP ( NNP December  )  ( CD 1998  )  )"
regex = re.compile("([\\w-]+)")

matches = re.findall(regex, s_expr)
# assert the s-expressions are 5
assert (len(matches) == 5)
print matches[0], matches[1], matches[3]
print matches[1], matches[2]
print matches[3], matches[4]
```

Here I assume all the s-expressions or trees have two descendents, if not, this is not gonna work and maybe a made-by-hand parser is better than a regex.

Comment: every node in my tree structure have 2 or one nodeand when i want to extract it's rule i do'nt know it's format(becaus it should be automatically extract.by your solution ,i can no t do it  automatically.

Comment: @serenei-fgufyurzt you can check the number matched, assert when they are pair, and loop over them, is pretty easy in my opinion, just that it's not very elegant (at all).